# Spark standalone mode on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, elastic-map-reduce

I'm able to run Spark on AWS EMR without much trouble following the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark.html) but from what I see it always uses YARN instead of the standalone manager. Is there any way to use the standalone mode instead of YARN easily? I don't really feel like hacking the bootstrap scripts to turn off yarn and deploy spark master/workers myself.

I'm running into a [weird YARN related bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12494) and I was hoping it won't happen with standalone manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there are no way to run in standalone mode on EMR unless you go back to the old ami-versions instead of using the emr-release-label. The old ami-version will however cause other problems with newer versions of Spark, so I wouldn't go that way.

What you can do is to launch ordinary EC2-instances with Spark instead of using EMR. If you have a local Spark installation, go to the `ec2` folder and use `spark-ec2` to launch the cluster, like this:

```
./spark-ec2 --copy-aws-credentials --key-pair=MY_KEY --identity-file=MY_PEM_FILE.pem --region=MY_PREFERED_REGION --instance-type=INSTANCE_TYPE --slaves=NUMBER_OF_SLAVES --hadoop-major-version=2 --ganglia launch NAME_OF_JOB
```

I suspect that you have jar-files that are needed, so they have to be copied onto the cluster (copy to master first, ssh to master and copy them onto the slaves from there. `./spark-ec2/copy-dir` on master will copy a directory onto all slaves). Then restart Spark:

```
./spark/sbin/stop-master.sh
./spark/sbin/stop-slaves.sh
./spark/sbin/start-master.sh
./spark/sbin/start-slaves.sh
```

and you are ready to launch Spark in standalone mode:

```
./spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client ...
```